# LibraryFatal.log is not accessible

Tags: debugging, xamarin.ios

Debugging a Xamarin iOS project, reaching an exception and trying to record it using

```
    internal static void LogUnhandledException(Exception exception)
    {
        try
        {
            const string errorFileName = "Fatal.log";
            var libraryPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources);
            var errorFilePath = libraryPath + errorFileName;
            var errorMessage = String.Format("Time: {0}\r\nError: Unhandled Exception\r\n{1}", DateTime.Now, exception.ToString());
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(errorFilePath, errorMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (App.debugging) { throw; };
            if (App.debugLogging) { App.ReportError(ex.ToString()); };
        }
    }
```

I am receiving another error message stating

> **System.UnauthorizedAccessException:** 'Access to the path "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B5DD413C-30B0-4B4B-B458-1BF6746FB953/LibraryFatal.log" is denied.'

Is this path on the MAC or the iPhone? Where? I am assuming that is being created during the initialization of debugging or perhaps by the GetFolderPath function. Or perhaps not and needs to be coded.

Searching, I haven't found any mention of the log online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is extensive [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#application-directories) on using the iOS file system.  Generally you want to use `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` to write to, but there are other choices - see the documentation for details